# Changing the element name and copying all attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this:

`<tab:column align="left" class="notdecorated" label="lab">
    <b>General Information</b>
 </tab:column>`

and I want to get this:

`<column align="left" class="notdecorated" label="lab">
    <b>General Information</b>
 <column>`

Here is my -incomplete- xslt transformator:

```
 <xsl:template match="tab:column">
    <column>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </column>
 </xsl:template>
```

It disregards the 'tab' part but does not copy the attributes. So I enriched it like this:

```
 <xsl:template match="tab:column">
    <column>
      <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </column>
 </xsl:template>
```

But that does not work either.
 So how can I copy the attributes AND change the elements name at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 <xsl:template match="tab:column">
    <column>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </column>
 </xsl:template>
```

or the identity transformation template plus

```
 <xsl:template match="tab:column">
    <column>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </column>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the fast answer, and because I have wasted sooo much time with xslt..

Comment: @Regenbogenfisch - Here's more info on the identity transform if you need it: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying